# App to keep notes on users

Tags: discussion, app-request, script-request

Is there an app around that makes notes on users?  Really all I am after is a flag to say -

**"Warning, this user is obnoxious, avoid arguments"**

**EDIT**

It could just colour coding, like red for avoid, green for go else unknown.  Working on just a browser would work.  It's not too much effort to add the same person on the browser on another machine.

Comment: @BrockAdams, I prefer to be happy and not get dragged into egos and name calling.  I gave up facebook because of this.  Maybe the app can color code the profile - red for "Angry Bull". Green for "Peaceful" else unknown.

Comment: I understand, just having fun. ... Clarify what is acceptable:  It's a lot easier to code a script, used on one machine and one browser, because it can use the browser for storage.  An app or script that will be used by different machines requires a central database.

Comment: The thing with this is that it wouldn't be very useful without a full on database with a lot of users using it - because if there was a database, people could 'report' users, add them to the database, and it updates for you, so if they had a bad experience with one user, they can tell the others there's no point arguing...